# Analysing the correctness of Fake Coin problem when using an inaccurate scale

Tags: algorithm, probability

Let's say we solve the fake coin problem with the "decrease by 3" algorithm, except the scale used is faulty. The probability of it tilting to one side when two piles are equal is p=0.4. What is the probability that our algorithm will produce the wrong answer in this situation?

Comment: you weight 3 times and need all of them to be correct in order to find the fake coin         1-(0.6)^3?

Comment: but on the other hand if it tilts to the heavier side it doesn't matter, so its not that simple